# Python openapi code keeps failing with errors

Tags: python, openai-api

My attempt at using the OpenAI API keeps returning errors.

I think the problem is that I am not retrieving the API key correctly.

Is there a way I can access the API without using the environ. method for storing the key

```
import os
import openai_secret_manager
import openai
# Add Key to environ
os.environ["api_key"] = "secret key....." # I got a real key from openai.com

# Retrieve key from environ.
openai.api_key = os.getenv("api_key")

# Test connectiom and list available API models
res = openai.Model.list()
print(res) # This works fine


# load the API key from the environment
secrets = openai_secret_manager.get_secret(openai.api_key) # L31 - this line triggers the error

# prompt for the API to generate text
prompt = "What is the meaning of life?"

# generate a response from the API
response = openai.Completion.create(
  engine="davinci",
  prompt=prompt,
  max_tokens=10,
  n=1,
  stop=None,
  temperature=0.5,
)

# print the generated text
print(response.choices[0].text)
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home/Dropbox/Python_general_work/work_in_progress/chatgpt/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    secrets = openai_secret_manager.get_secret(openai.api_key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai_secret_manager.py", line 6, in get_secret
    return openai_secret_manager.get_secret(key_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai_secret_manager.py", line 6, in get_secret
    return openai_secret_manager.get_secret(key_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai_secret_manager.py", line 6, in get_secret
    return openai_secret_manager.get_secret(key_name)
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a recursive function call:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home/Dropbox/Python_general_work/work_in_progress/chatgpt/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    secrets = openai_secret_manager.get_secret(openai.api_key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai_secret_manager.py", line 6, in get_secret
    return openai_secret_manager.get_secret(key_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai_secret_manager.py", line 6, in get_secret
    return openai_secret_manager.get_secret(key_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai_secret_manager.py", line 6, in get_secret
    return openai_secret_manager.get_secret(key_name)
```

`openai_secret_manager.get_secret` calls `openai_secret_manager.get_secret` which calls `openai_secret_manager.get_secret` and so on...

I don't know what this actually is, but following the official [Usage](https://github.com/openai/openai-python#usage) examples would look like this. There also does not seem a need for you to programmatically set and retrieve the environment variable:

```
import openai
openai.api_key = "sk-..." # Your key


# prompt for the API to generate text
prompt = "What is the meaning of life?"

# generate a response from the API
response = openai.Completion.create(
  engine="davinci",
  prompt=prompt,
  max_tokens=10,
  n=1,
  stop=None,
  temperature=0.5,
)

# print the generated text
print(response.choices[0].text)
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared the recursive error. I now get a new eror: openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. Which is strange as Ive only connect to the api a few times.

Comment: Glad it cleared your problem. I have not worked with the APi to a great extend, but it sounds like something that you need to adress to their customer support